# Why does a path work even if it contains an @ before "\\"

Tags: c#, string

Im a bit confused. I thought "@" in c# ist a sign for to interpret text literally like @"C:\Users...". It avoids the need of a double backslash.

But why does paths also work if they contain double backslashes and the @? 
Fe:

```
var temp = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\text.txt").ToString(); // no error
```

I that case the string must be literally "C:\\Users\\text.txt" - because of the previous "@" - which is not a valid windows path (EDIT: Thats wrong, it is a valid Path, only explorer wont accept it - thanks to  Muctadir Dinar), so why does this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: multiple path separators are interpreted as single path separator.

Comment: It is a valid path. Try cd command in command prompt(cmd) with multiple path separator.

Comment: Thank you Muctadir Dinari, I tried this in explorer which throws an error, i didnt thought about cmd. Also Thanks gp, this is important to know (i searched Msdn before and dont find anything).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because internally `FileStream` during initialization calls iternal `Path.NormalizePath(path, true, maxPathLength)` method to normalize passed path value.

You can call this method with reflection (it has overload, so getting MethodInfo is a little bit tricky):

```
string path = @"C:\\Users\\text.txt";
Type type = typeof(Path);
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var binder = Type.DefaultBinder;
var types = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(bool), typeof(int) };
var modifiers = new ParameterModifier[0];

var normalize = type.GetMethod("NormalizePath", flags, binder, types, modifiers);
var result = normalize.Invoke(null, new object[] { path, true, 256});
```

Output:

> C:\Users\text.txt

Comment: Thanks for this detailed and well explained answer.

Comment: @Pengu welcome :) You can investigate NormalizePath implementation with some disassembler like Reflector. BTW removing double backslashes is implemented very simply - when checking path char by char, it checks if current char is directory separator char. If so, then separator is appended to result, and flag (which shows that last added char was directory separator) is changed to `true`. All other directory separator chars will not be added to result until some non-separator char will be found (that will reset flag)

Answer (score 5):

All of these are valid paths:

```
C:\Users\text.txt
C:\\Users\\text.txt
C:\\\Users\\\text.txt
C:\\\\Users\\\\text.txt
```

`"\\"` represents `"\"`
`@"\"` represents `"\"`
`@"\\"` represents `"\\"`
`"\\\\"` represents `"\\"`

So your `@"C:\\Users\\text.txt"` represents `"C:\\\\Users\\\\text.txt"` which is valid

You can call `Path.GetFullPath("")` to get the absolute path.

for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"C:\\Users\\text.txt");
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\\Users\\text.txt"));
```

> Output:
>   C:\\Users\\text.txt
>   C:\Users\text.txt

Answer (score 2):

that string @"C:\Users\text.txt" will be parsed with repetitive backslash chars but the system ignore these repetitive chars by considering them as one.
for example, this code will also work:

```
string s=File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\\Users\\\text.txt");
```

or:

```
string s=File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\\\\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\\\\text.txt");
```

but it is not a good idea to do so.
if you iterate through the chars inside those path strings, you will see that there are actually several backslash chars.

```
foreach (char c in @"C:\\\Users\\\text.txt") ...
```

> Note: you should avoid specifying more than one backslash as folder separator as this behavior is not reliable and may be changed in future versions of operating system or .net framework ...